# jQuery not working with runat="server"

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My below code is working fine when used in HTML. The same code I tried to place it inside a form and it stopped working. How to fix this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" ></script>
<title>Chat scroll test</title>
<style type="text/css">
#chat
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
</style>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        monitor = function () {
            var $this = $(this),
        wrap = $this.find('.wrapper'),
        height = $this.height(),
        maxScroll = wrap.height() - height,
        top = $this.scrollTop();
            if (maxScroll === top) {
                $this.addClass('atBottom');
            } else {
                $this.removeClass('atBottom');
            }
        }
        window.setInterval(function () {
            monitor.call($('#chat').get(0));
        }, 350);
        $('#chat').bind('addMessage', function (e, message) {
            var $this = $(this),
        top = $this.scrollTop(),
        scroll = $this.hasClass('atBottom');
            $this.find('.wrapper').append(message);
            if (scroll) {
                var wrap = $this.find('.wrapper'),
            height = $this.height(),
            maxScroll = wrap.height() - height
                $this.scrollTop(maxScroll);
            }
        })
        $('button').click(function () {
            $('#chat').trigger('addMessage', 'asdgagasdg<br/>');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="chat">
    <div class="wrapper">
        adsgasgda<br/>
        adsgasg<br/>
        asd<br/>
        adsgasgda<br/>
        adsgasg<br/>
        adsgasgda<br/>
        adsgasg<br/>
        adsgasgda<br/>
        adsgasg<br/>
        adsgasgda<br/>
        adsgasg<br/>
        adsgasgda<br/>
        adsgasg<br/>
        adsgasgda<br/>
        adsgasg<br/>
    </div>
</div>
<button>Add a line</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When form tag is removed it again starts back to work.

Comment: If you look at the HTML on your browser are all the element IDs as you expect them to be?

Comment: what .net version your using?

Comment: yeah! everything is working fine when opened without <form> tag.

Comment: Add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to all your server side tags/controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a  inside a  automatically submits the form.
Replace the

```
<button>Add a line</button>
```

with a

```
<input type="button" value="Add a line" />
```

and that way the browser doesn't post the form when it's clicked.

Remember also to change the jQuery selector from

```
$('button').click(function () {
```

to something like

```
$(':button').click(function () {
```

Answer (score 7):

For .NET 4.0 add **ClientIDMode Static** for tags to appear on client side the sameway they appear on server side.

Something like

```
                  <form id="form1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

For old .net use '<%= Control.ClientID %>' in your jQuery/Javascript code whenever you are refering to a control

Something like

```
                 '<%= form1.ClientID %>'
```

Comment: Can you please post HTML generated by running your code. What tags have you added `ClientIDMode="Static"`?

Comment: By adding `ClientIDMode="Static"` I am getting the same output that I got when its not placed.!

Comment: I have already posted by HTML code right? copy that code and try in your system. Anyways I found the answer from Andres. And also thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Look at the ID's of the code in the final HTML.

This should give you an idea of what's going.  There are a number of solutions to this, but that depends on what version of .net you are using.

Comment: I am using .NET 4.0 and don't know what is MVC.